# Categorical encoding in regression task

Tags: classification, categorical-data, scikit-learn

I have a categorical variable, country which takes on values like India, US, Pakistan etc. I am currently using a linear SLM for a classification task.

So my country value varies from 1-20.
How should this be a feature in the classification task.
Should i have a one hot vector like (1,0,0..) for us and assign this vector 20 weights, or should i have integer from 1_20 and assign a single weight?
I am using scikit learn. Does the answer depend on classifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that yes, it depends on the classifier. It's feature engineering and in my opinion the choice of the categorical encoding is kind of like the choice of hyperparameters : you have to cross-validate which one seems to be working the best and with which algorithm.

Just so you know, you can use one-hot encoding or label encoding (integer from 1 to 20) but you can also use other encodings, some listed here : https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding

Another notable point is that you can also learn a representation of your categorical variable in a higher dimension (not only one number but a vector of *d* numbers). This is often called "embeddings" and is famously known for words (word2vec) but can be used for any categorical variable.

Hope it helps a bit